# Linear Layout remove spacing between elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a ListView with the following Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ok" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This produces the following Layout:

[image: Current Layout]

But I want to get rid of the empty space on the left side of the images, and position the text right next to the images:

[image: Future Layout]

I already tried setting padding and margin to 0dp but that didn't work.

EDIT: The LinearLayout I posted is part of a ConstraintLayout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.beric.listviewtest.MyListActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my_list">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/feed_fragment_portrait"
        class="com.beric.listviewtest.MyListFragment"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `ListView` layout as well.

Comment: add full layout

Comment: may be your drawable image have that padding check it, use orientation horizontal to linear layout

Answer (score 0):

you can try ..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:text="title of the next to image"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="35dp"` in the `ImageView`. Below the working code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ok" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20dp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's not good practice to set the dimens of an ImageView... it'll look bad with  a device with vastly different specs.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your image doesn't have any padding. if your image view has some padding than add the `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in your imageview.